# Password is not hashed before storing in database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

This is the `AppController` code:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');
}

public function beforeSave()
{
    if(isset($this->data['Admin']['password']))
    {
        $this->data['Admin']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['Admin']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is the `AdminsController` code:

```
public $name = 'Admins';

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
    $this->Auth->allow('signup');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->Admin->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('admins', $this->Admin->find('all'));
}

public function login()
{
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Polkadot - Admin Login');

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login successfull!');
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login failed!');
        }
    }
}

public function signup()
{
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Polkadot - Admin Sign Up');

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->Admin->save($this->request->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Account created successfully!');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Account could not be created, please try again!');
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the account is created but the password in the database is plain text. When I try to log in, it fails. What have I done wrong ?

I want the `index` action of the `Dashboard` controller to be opened when the admin logs in. The account registration uses four input fields: name (text), email (text), password (password) and password_confirm (password). And so, the log in form uses two fields: email (text) and password (password).

CakePHP version used is 2.3.1

All help appreciated!

**[EDIT]:** Here is the error log

```
2013-04-10 19:31:13 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'CssController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /polkapanel/css/cake.generic.css
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\polkapanel\app\webroot\index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2013-04-10 19:31:13 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ImgController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'ImgController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /polkapanel/img/cake.power.gif
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\polkapanel\app\webroot\index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2013-04-10 19:31:25 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'CssController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /polkapanel/css/cake.generic.css
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\polkapanel\app\webroot\index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2013-04-10 19:31:25 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ImgController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'ImgController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /polkapanel/img/cake.power.gif
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\polkapanel\app\webroot\index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

Comment: There's no beforeSave() function in the controller, it should go on the model (AppModel or User.ctp, depends on where you want to manage passwords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the `beforeSave` function in your `Admin` model:

Admin.php (or whatever you call it):

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if(isset($this->data['Admin']['password'])) {
        $this->data['Admin']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['Admin']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah what a stupid mistake I made. So, now the password is hashed before being stored in the database. But still the login is failing. In the login() function, do I have to again hash the password entered by the admin before it verifies with the stored password ? If yes, how do I do that ?

Comment: Could you put the error log? You don't need to verify the password in the `login` method, CakePHP does it automatically

Comment: Added the log in problem description above.

Comment: This is what I got when I printed the data in login() function:

Array ( [Admin] => Array ( [email] => shubham@mysite.com [password] => mypass123 ) )

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I had not defined the `userModel` to the model that I am using here. So every time, the authentication was happening through a User table instead of Admin table.